# Which kind of Singleton is this?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private static Map <String, ConnectionManager> managerInstances = new HashMap<String, ConnectionManager>();

    private String dsKey;
    private ConnectionManager(String dsKey){
        this.dsKey = dsKey;
    }

    public static ConnectionManager getInstance(String dsKey){
        ConnectionManager managerInstance = managerInstances.get(dsKey);

        if (managerInstance == null) {
            synchronized (ConnectionManager.class) {
                managerInstance = managerInstances.get(dsKey);
                if (managerInstance == null) {
                    managerInstance = new ConnectionManager(dsKey);
                    managerInstances.put(dsKey, managerInstance);
                }
            }
        }
        return managerInstance;
    }
}
```

I recently saw this code somewhere where the Singleton pattern was not used as per book definition from GoF. Singleton is storing a `Map` of its own instances.

What kind of singleton can this be called? Or is this a valid use of Singleton?

Comment: @assylias While I won't disagree with (entirely ;)) an explanation might be nice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a singleton. It's called [multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern).

> Rather than have a single instance *per application*, the multiton pattern instead ensures a single instance *per key*.

Answer (score 4):

That multiton seems broken as it uses a double-checked locking idiom which is not thread safe in Java. In particular, when calling `getInstance(s)`, with `s` a non-null String, you could receive a non-null reference pointing to a `ConnectionManager` whose `dsKey` is null.

It would be much better to use a thread safe ConcurrentHashMap instead and remove the need for synchronization.

Comment: As far as thread safety, it gets worse than that -- even if all the locking worked as the programmer thought it would.  Time it just right, where one thread's getting from the map while another's writing to it, and the stars align, and [you can end up in an infinite loop](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html).  It ain't just occasional lost or duplicate data we're talking about when we say "corruption", people.  :P

Comment: @cHao Yes I had stopped looking before I had noticed that crucial point!

Comment: The double-checked locking can be made thread safe with `volatile`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: @mike That won't be enough in this case because (a) volatile will only apply to the map but not its content and (b) that does not solve the issue raised by cHao that if you put and get at the same time, the HashMap might become inconsistent (HashMap is not thread-safe).

Comment: I meant adding volatile to `ConnectionManager managerInstance` to avoid the problems that come with double-checked locking, i. e. ending up with two freshly created instances instead of one.

Comment: @mike you can't add volatile to `ConnectionManager managerInstance`: it is a local variable.

Comment: What a pity. Hmm... maybe he can declare it as class variable `current`. Then at least the instance creation would be safe. And if `ConnectionManager` is properly synchronized, he wouldn't have to worry about the HashMap. ...That's all I have right now!

Comment: @mike as long as the `get` is outside the synchronized block, all bets are off, even if you use a temporary volatile field to hold the result. I'm afraid there are only two (painless) ways: make the method synchronized or use a thread safe map implementation such as ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: @assylias I provided a - what I hope to be - thread-safe implementation without the use of `ConcurrentHashMap` and `volatile`. Since it would be a little off-topic, I posted an own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147113/thread-safe-multiton-pattern I would be happy, if you added your thoughts.